# Robotframework, AutoIt: Error message "No keyword with name 'Send' found"

Tags: robotframework, autoit

I'm trying to get familiar with the robotframework using autoitlibrary to test Windows applications. I found some examples which use the `Send` command to type text into a notpad window.

That's what I've done so far:

```
*** Settings ***
Library           AutoItLibrary

*** Variables ***
${app}            C:/Program Files/Notepad++/notepad++.exe

*** Test Cases ***
Enter text
    Run    ${app}
    Win Wait Active    new 1 - Notepad++
    Send    This is just a test.
```

So, the Notepad++ window is opened, but then it failed with the `No keyword with name 'Send' found.` message. I suppose there is no `Send` command in the `AutoItLibrary`, but I also cannot find any other command which may do this job.

AutoIt is installed, and so is the wrapper by `pip install robotframework-autoitlibrary`.

There really exists a [Send keyword in AutoIt](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/appendix/SendKeys.htm), but supposedly not in the wrapper for robotframework.

And ideas to fix this?

**UPDATE:** Windows 10 (64bit in a VirtualBox), Python v3.7.6 (32bit), RF v3.1.2, RF-AutoItLibrary v1.2.4, AutoIt v3.3.14.5

The "Search Keywords" dialog in RIDE provides AutoItLibrary as a Source, but then list only a few commands. So I suppose the library is accessible, but incomplete.
[image]

Comment: Which python version do you use? I've installed autoitlibrary on python2.7 and it works fine.

Comment: It's 3.7 (3.8 doesn't work, according to the documentation). I suppose it has difficulties to find the library, although the entry is displayed in black. I tried it with Py3.6 today on a different machine, which works fine.

Comment: The methods that you have listed in RIDE are in the Class of `AutoItLibrary` in the file `__init__.py`. The descriptions come from the methods doc strings. So all other methods in the AutoItX DLL are not shown.

Comment: @michael_heath Yes, they are - on a different machine everything looks fine, also the keywords. I suppose the order of installation makes the difference. I'll check that soon and report.

Comment: @ChristophJüngling, thanks for that info about RIDE etc. My answer posted is focused on the win32com cache workings and RIDE seems like another set of problems. All I see in RIDEs Search Keywords is the Builtins as tested with Python 3.5 and 3.6.

Comment: @michael_heath Thanks for the analysis. That may explain that after a complete de- and installation (AutoIt before RF's AutoItLibrary) everything looks fine now.

Comment: Thank you all for your help! After a fresh installation now anything works as intended. I can't say  what was wrong, sorry.

Answer (score 2):

```python
import os, re, subprocess, sys

# Set path to Python directories.
programfiles = os.environ['programfiles']
if not programfiles:
    exit('Failed to get programfiles')

python_dirs = [os.path.join(programfiles, 'Python35'),
               os.path.join(programfiles, 'Python36'),
               os.path.join(programfiles, 'Python37'),
               os.path.join(programfiles, 'Python38')]

# Process each python directory.
for python_dir in python_dirs:
    print('---')

    # Set path to AutoItX3.dll.
    autoitx_dll = os.path.join(python_dir, r'Lib\site-packages\AutoItLibrary\lib\AutoItX3.dll')
    if not os.path.isfile(autoitx_dll):
        print('File not found: "' + autoitx_dll + '"')
        continue

    # Set path to the makepy module.
    makepy = os.path.join(python_dir, r'Lib\site-packages\win32com\client\makepy.py')
    if not os.path.isfile(makepy):
        print('File not found: "' + makepy + '"')
        continue

    # Generate cache using make.py.
    command = [os.path.join(python_dir, 'python.exe'), makepy, autoitx_dll]

    with subprocess.Popen(command, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, cwd=python_dir, universal_newlines=True) as p:
        stderr = p.communicate()[1]
        print(stderr.rstrip())

        parameters = re.findall(r'^Generating to .+\\([A-F0-9\-]+)x(\d+)x(\d+)x(\d+)\.py$', stderr, re.M)

        if len(parameters) == 1:
            parameters = parameters[0]

            print('Insert the next line into AutoItLibrary.__init__.py if not exist.\n'
                  '  win32com.client.gencache.EnsureModule("{{{guid}}}", {major}, {minor}, {lcid})'
                  .format(guid=parameters[0],
                          major=parameters[1],
                          minor=parameters[2],
                          lcid=parameters[3]))

# Pause so the user can view the subprocess output.
input('Press the return key to continue...')
```

The generated cache done by `win32com\client\makepy.py` for AutoItLibrary from the `setup.py` is saved in the `%temp%\gen_py` folder. This is done only when `setup.py` is executed. If the `%temp%` directory is cleaned later, which removes the cache, then I notice keywords like `Send` may fail to be recognized by the robotframework.

One solution appears to be regenerating the cache. The code above will generate the cache by use of `makepy.py`. It may also print a message about inserting `win32com.client.gencache.EnsureModule(...)` into `AutoItLibrary\__init__.py` for any of the Python versions as needed. This will ensure the cache is available when AutoItLibrary
is imported.

Change paths in the code to suit your environment.

---

With further research:

- AutoItLibrary currently has AutoItX 3.3.6.1 and latest AutoIt has AutoItX 3.3.14.5. Important to know as one version registered can overwrite the registration of the previous registration.
- AutoItLibrary currently registers AutoIt3X.dll without the `_x64` suffix on the name on x64 systems. I may reference AutoIt3_x64.dll to define difference between x86 and x64.
- Any version of AutoIt3X.dll and AutoIt3_x64.dll uses the same ID codes and the last registered wins (based on bitness as both x86 and x64 registrations can co-exist).
  The `TypeLib` class key registered ID is `{F8937E53-D444-4E71-9275-35B64210CC3B}` and is where `win32com` may search.
- If AutoIt3X.dll and AutoIt3_x64.dll are registered, unregister any 1 of those 2 will remove the `AutoItX3.Control` class key. Without this key, AutoIt3X will fail as AutoItLibrary needs this key. To fix, register again e.g. `regsvr32.exe AutoIt3X.dll` as admin in the working directory of `AutoIt3X.dll`.
- The methods of any same version of AutoItX will match i.e. `AutoIt3X.dll` and `AutoIt3X_x64.dll` only changes in bitness, not methods.

Inserting `win32com.client.gencache.EnsureModule("{F8937E53-D444-4E71-9275-35B64210CC3B}", 0, 1, 0)` into `AutoItLibrary\__init__.py` should ensure the cache is always available for any AutoItX version. The initial code can be used to generate the cache, though the suggested change in `AutoItLibrary\__init__.py` makes it obsolete as the cache is generated on import of `AutoItLibrary`. If the ID was not constant, then the initial code may inform you of the ID to use.

The cache is important as it has generated .py files with methods like e.g.:

> ```python
>        def Send(self, strSendText=defaultNamedNotOptArg, nMode=0):
>            'method Send'
>            # etc...
> ```

which if missing, makes `Send` and many others, an invalid keyword in AutoItLibrary.

If AutoItX 3.3.14.5 is registered, the `-` leading methods are removed and the `+` leading methods are added as compared to AutoItX 3.3.6.1:

> ```python
> -BlockInput
> -CDTray
> -IniDelete
> -IniRead
> -IniWrite
> -RegDeleteKey
> -RegDeleteVal
> -RegEnumKey
> -RegEnumVal
> -RegRead
> -RegWrite
> -RunAsSet
> +RunAs
> +RunAsWait
> ```

So if any of those methods causes error, then you may want AutoItX 3.3.6.1 registered instead. In the AutoItX history, 3.3.10.0 release is when those method changes happened.

Answer (score 0):

**Fix:**

**Check your python architecture ( is it 32 or 64 bit)**

**For 32:**

1. Open cmd in "**Run as administrator**" mode
2. run the command `pip install robotframework-autoitlibrary`
3. Now clone the autoit library source code:
   https://github.com/nokia/robotframework-autoitlibrary
4. in the root directory run the below command: `python setup.py install` using cmd in admin mode

**to navigate to root directory use the command `pushd <filepath>' instead of`cd ` if cd doesn't work in cmd opened in admin mode.**

**For 64:**

1. Open cmd in "**Run as administrator**" mode
2. Now clone the autoit library source code:
   https://github.com/nokia/robotframework-autoitlibrary
3. in the root directory run the below command: `python setup.py install` using cmd in admin mode

**to navigate to root directory use the command `pushd <filepath>' instead of`cd ` if cd doesn't work in cmd opened in admin mode.**